# How to redirect website links from old URL structure to a new URL strucre

Tags: .htaccess

I changed my website url structure

FROM :

`http://mywebsite.com/?page=example.php`

TO :

`http://mywebsite.com/example.php`

AND FROM :

`http://mywebsite.com/?page=profile.php&u_i = 10`

TO :

`http://mywebsite.com/profile.php?u_i=10`

So I add to the htaccess file this codes to convert from the old to the new structure to know lose the power of SEO of my old links:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)&u_i=([^&]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1?u_i=%2 [NC,R,L]
```

My problem is that this code just solve the second case when there is a parameter in the URL , but the first case still not solved , I want to know if I miss something in that code , should I add or edit something to include the first case also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, just add a "**?**" to the end of your second regular expression, to make it optional eg.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)(&u_i=[^&]+)? [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2                                   [R,L]
```